# How to resolve localhost access problem docker wsl?

Tags: localhost, windows-subsystem-for-linux, virtualhost

I have a php app with nginx running in wsl docker container Ubuntu 20.04. The problem is when I connect to http://test.loc via browser I get the error "The requested URL was not found on this server.Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at test.loc Port 80". But when I make a request to the same url in postman, it works. Other docker services work fine.

curl http://test.loc gets 404 both from windows and ubuntu.

P.S
Everithing worked fine a week or two ago.

Answer (score 1):

command "sudo service apache2 stop" inside wsl solved my issue. But still not clear how postman got correct response.